# mysqli_query() returning a boolean value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a piece of PHP code I am using to grab the 20 next messages in a database.

```
<?php
    $user_email_msg = "bob@gmail.com";
    $msg_email = "sam@gmail.com";
    $start_query_msg = 1;
    $end_query_msg = $start_query_msg-20;
    $user_link_msg = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", $user_email_msg);
    $query_msg = "SELECT * FROM " . $msg_email . " WHERE id BETWEEN " . (string)$end_query_msg . " AND " . (string)$start_query_msg;
    $result_msg = mysqli_query($user_link_msg, $query_msg);

    $row_msg = mysqli_fetch_all($result_msg, MYSQLI_NUM);

    $next_20 = $row_msg[0];

    print_r($next_20);
?>
```

When I run this code I get this error message:

> "Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\jayden\messages.php on line 10"

I am so lost here, because I can't see any way that `$result_msg` can be returning a boolean value.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Print the query and execute it manually using phpMyAdmin or your MySQL command prompt. If it works, use `mysqli_error()` to know what exactly is going wrong. If not, fix your query.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but most likely your fourth parameter to mysqli_connect is not an email address but should rather be the database name

Comment: The first of many problems, I'm sure ;)

Comment: I would assume the same for the table name in the query.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` the variable `$query_msg` and run the query in phpmyadmin or any favorite application. The error is about mistake in sql query check that now.

Answer (score 0):

print the query and check if the query is ok.

```
print_r($query_msg);
```

this problem occurs when your query is not right.